How to handle very long letter recipient business name
When following the German national standard DIN 5008, how should I handle very long letter recipient business name that overflow the 85mm box?
Example


The sole purpose of these measurements is that, if wrapping a letter with a window envelope, the address stays visible within the window. If that is not your use case, matching the measurements does not apply.
Just wrap the name in two lines. As long as you restrict the complete address field to 85 mm horizontally and 45 mm vertically, everything is fine. For readability, hyphenation should be avoided if at all possible, and logical grouping of words (for example enforced through non-breaking spaces) is a good practice.
It is common practice to handle the address field as a block with a variable number of lines. If you want to strictly conform to DIN 5008, this page gives practical instructions. The current version of the norm (2020) says the field should be divided into two parts:

the upper part for a return address (one line) plus additions and remarks (a maximum of four lines) at a line height of 10 points = 3.353 mm, 17.7 mm total,
and the lower part for the address with a maximum of six lines at a line height of 12 points = 4.233 mm, 27.3 mm total.


It is up to you how many of these lines you use, if you don't need them all, all the better. For the upper part, align the used lines to the bottom, for the lower part, to the top.
Normally, you won't need more than between three and six for the lower part: one or two for the recipient, one for the street address, optionally one for additional identifications, one for the postal code and city, and for international letters an extra line for the country.
If that is not enough, you might be forced to reduce the line height. Personally, I would rather redistribute the total space and reduce the height for the upper part of the field. I have never seen all five lines being used there.
If you need more information about formating of addresses in Germany, the Universal Postal Union has a data sheet about German postal standards.
The same reasoning applies for the positioning of the top of the main text field. If a letter is folded twice horizontally to fit a longform envelope, the date line should end up above the first fold at 105 mm, its top at 94 mm from the paper edge.

And for aesthetic reasons and legibility I would try to keep logical groups together when using multiple lines, so don’t split (internationale Kooperation e.V.) if possible.

I got the impression the question was geared for software implementations and thus automation. Grouping words in this case is a bit tricky; but one rule should be followed in any case: No Hyphenation!

Probably yes, but it won’t hurt for future readers who are interested in a similar problem sans automation.

Use abbreviations that keep the characteristic parts intact but shorten the standards: "Dt. Sparkassenstift. f. intern. Kooperation"
(The e.V. = eingetragener Verein is a very german-specific company format and can be removed for address purposes...)
